# Is $\cot(x)=\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I just found in some [place](http://www.uhigh.ilstu.edu/math/sondgeroth/coll%20alg/09%20col%20alg%20notes%20072%20trig%20identities%20pt%202.htm) say that $\cot(x)=\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$. 
If you think about it as a function they are definitely not same. but if you think about as a relation between angle in a right angle triangle and its side they will be equal. 
so the question is its right to say they are equal or not( at least pedagogically)?

Update:-
Even [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain%201%2Ftan(x)) and [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dqkcn5lcns) say they are not equal ( have different domain).

Comment: $\cot$ is defined to be $1/\tan$.

Comment: @henry  I agree that, technically, $\tan$ and $\cot$ have different domain, but definitely $\cot x=\frac{1}{\tan x}$ where both functions are defined ( say, if $x$ is not an integer multiple of $\frac\pi2$ ). There are ways to see it, but it depends on the definition you gave of $\tan$ and $\cot$.

Comment: @HenryW. they defined in both way but they have different domain.

Comment: We can also regard them as power series, and then they are the same power series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have $\cot(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ and $x\ne k\pi$ $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ and $x\ne \frac{2k+1)}{2}\pi$ and $$\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$$ is defined for all $x$ with $\tan(x) \ne 0$ and this is if $\sin(x)\ne 0$ if $x\ne k\pi$ with $x\in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your perspective. It is true that, in elementary mathematics, the two functions aren't the same because of domain issues.

However, in the realm of [meromorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function), they *are* the same function. The explanation, briefly put, is that you add a “point at infinity” to the complex numbers, call it $\infty$, and declare that $1/0=\infty$ and $1/\infty=0$. You don't really *need* the complex numbers to do that; you can do it to the reals too, but then note that we don't distinguish between $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.

Until you learn about meromorphic functions, this may seem a bit ad hoc. That is why basic calculus books would rather avoid the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The tangent is defined as $$\tan\alpha =\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\sin~\alpha}{\cos~\alpha}$$
and the cotangent as 
$$\cot\alpha =\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{opposite}}=\frac{b}{a}=\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha} $$
what leads us to 
$$\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha} = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\right) = \frac{1}{\tan \alpha} = \cot\alpha$$
so yes, they are equivalent.

The confusing thing about it is, that you would have to consider the roots of the cosine function, if you were evaluating the tangent function in the denominator before evaluating the fraction.

This is actually a big dissent between different (functional) programming languages, as there is actually no "right order" of evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Pedagogically, we say that that equality holds. We have to fudge it a bit on where the functions are defined (which is sometimes achieved by allowing $\tan(x)$ to be infinite) but we generally say that that equality holds.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cot x = \frac {\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac {1}{\frac {\sin x}{\cos x}} = \frac {1}{\tan x}$$

This is true only when $\cot x$ and $\tan x$ are defined.

This equation merely indicates that $\cot x$ and $\frac {1}{\tan x}$ are equal in value (when they are both defined, of course). It does *not* say that $\cot x$ and $\frac {1}{\tan x}$ are the same function.

Comment: Thanks, but I saw it in a school textbook ( not english) they used them as a  same functions, but yes I agree with you if they both defined then they will be same.

Comment: @henry Maybe in your textbook there are restrictions to $x$ so that these two functions are defined by default. Providing the context in your question will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered a similar issue in discussing the graph of the function  $ \ \log (x^2 \ - \ 3 x \ + \ 2) \ $ .  We usually say (and teach) that this equals $ \ \log( x \ - \ 1 ) \ + \ \log ( x \ - \ 2 ) \ $ , but the former function is defined on $ \ ( -\infty \ , \ 1 ) \ , \ ( 2  \ , \  \infty) \ $ , while the latter sum function is defined only on $ \ ( 2 \  , \ \infty) \ $ .  To say a bit differently what others have said here, the equation for an identity only has meaning when the expressions on *both* sides of the equation have defined values.  (It is easy to forget this in applying or teaching such equations, unfortunately.)  To paraphrase **Yuxiao Xie** on this page, the equation *doesn't imply* that the two expressions being equated represent *exactly* the same function (though, again, this often gets overlooked because of the ways in which we usually use such equations).

It is a bit like the equation in the definition for continuity of a function at a point*, $ \ \lim_{x \ \rightarrow \ a} \ f(x) \ = \ f(a) \ $ . In explaining this definition, we often point out that there are *three* conditions being required:  that $ \ f(x) \ $ be *defined* at $ \ x \ = \ a \ $ ; that the two-sided limit $ \ \lim_{x \ \rightarrow \ a} \ f(x) \ $ *exists* ; and finally, with the expressions on each side having a meaningful value, that these two values be the same.  (It's these sorts of "fussy" points that are sometimes vital in mathematics, as they can lead to pitfalls when neglected -- even though they may seem pedantic.)

$ * $ if you haven't had calculus yet, but are going to later on, you'll meet this early in the course